# Numpy array: group by one column, sum another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that looks like this:

```
 array([[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 1,  1,  6],
        [ 2,  2, 10],
        [ 3,  2, 14]])
```

I want to sum the values of the third column that have the same value in the second column, so the result is something is:

```
 array([[ 0,  1,  8],
        [ 1,  2, 24]])
```

I started coding this but I'm stuck with this sum:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

inFile = sys.argv[1]

with open(inFile, 'r') as t:
    f = np.genfromtxt(t, delimiter=None, names =["1","2","3"])

f.sort(order=["1","2"])
if value == previous.value:
   sum(f["3"])
```

Comment: To clarify, it looks like your first column is a row number index, and doesn't have any regard for your data.  You then want your second column to be the unique set of elements in that column, and the third column to be the sum of the existing third column for each of those set elements.  Is your data already sorted by the second column, as it is in your example?

Comment: Yes, this is the data after being sorted. I just added a first column as indication that I have columns with "useless" information

Comment: If you omit that column it's actually a lot easier.

Comment: Have you considered using pandas? It generates the index column and does grouping for you.

Comment: @Anom, if one of the below solutions helped, consider accepting it (green tick on left) so other users know.

Answer (score 7):

If your data is sorted by the second column, you can use something centered around [`np.add`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html).[`reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) for a pure numpy solution. A combination of [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) (or [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)) applied to [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) will give you the locations where the second column switches values. You can use those indices to do the sum-reduction. The other columns are pretty formulaic, so you can concatenate them back in fairly easily:

```
A = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],
              [ 1,  1,  6],
              [ 2,  2, 10],
              [ 3,  2, 14]])
# Find the split indices
i = np.nonzero(np.diff(A[:, 1]))[0] + 1
i = np.insert(i, 0, 0)
# Compute the result columns
c0 = np.arange(i.size)
c1 = A[i, 1]
c2 = np.add.reduceat(A[:, 2], i)
# Concatenate the columns
result = np.c_[c0, c1, c2]
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/2M3t8Q)

Notice the +1 in the indices. That is because you always want the location *after* the switch, not before, given how `reduceat` works. The insertion of zero as the first index could also be accomplished with [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html), [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), etc.

That being said, I still think you are looking for the pandas version in [@jpp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49238616/2988730).

Comment: Hi, I think your solution is what I'm looking for but I have a problem with IndexError : too many indices. The array shape is (x,) (x is a number)

Comment: Are you passing in a 1D array somewhere without realizing it?

Comment: Yes, I checked that when I import the array from the external file and I assign names to the columns, it is changed from a 2D to a 1D

Comment: A comment regarding this solution vs `pandas.groupby`: this pure `numpy` solution is *a lot* faster.

Comment: @Ketil. Numpy generally tends to be a bit faster. But also less legible and harder to use for the more complex problems.

Comment: @MadPhysicist absolutely; it just might be useful for people looking to speed things up to see how to avoid `pandas`. It may be ugly, but it sure is fast!

Comment: why does `numpy` not have a reasonable (/legible) solution for `groupby` - which is such a fundamental construct?

Comment: @javadba. Because that is what pandas is for. It's simply not part of the niche that numpy is filling to the best of its ability.

Comment: Are there libraries for rounding out `numpy` for this and other basic operations - _in place_ ?  The _pandas_ is too heavyweight for forward/backward conversion - both performance wise and in added code complexity - when _numpy_ is sufficient for the bulk of the logic needs (e.g. vector manipulation) and only a couple of _groupby_'s are needed. Another question mentions also that your solution here is "much" faster than the _pandas_ equivalent - and that may not even take into account the cost of conversion.

Comment: @javadba. If you feel so strongly about this, I would recommend raising an issue on the numpy GitHub page. At the very least, you'd hear the maintainers' rationale for not having it. If your argument was strong enough, you'd likely see a much better implementation than mine come into existence.

Comment: Just looked - there was already a proposal https://www.numpy.org/neps/nep-0008-groupby_additions.html .  It was "deferred" but no explanation provided as to why and what path forward there will be - if any.  I'm still looking for lightweight library[/ies] that "patch" numpy. Even just a collection of snippets along the lines of what you have above.

Comment: @javadba. The generalized groupby is not this simple, and numpy tries to keep it as general as possible. Perhaps this is something you'd consider contributing to?

Comment: @MadPhysicist This was quite helpful, as I wanted a pure NumPy solution for something similar at work. Later while having dinner, I realized my problem could be done with a bin count-based one-liner. After reviewing OP's problem again, I'm pretty sure a hist might do the trick here. Will post an ans soon.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pandas` to vectorize your algorithm:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

A = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],
              [ 1,  1,  6],
              [ 2,  2, 10],
              [ 3,  2, 14]])

df = pd.DataFrame(A)\
       .groupby(1, as_index=False)\
       .sum()\
       .reset_index()

res = df[['index', 1, 2]].values
```

**Result**

```
array([[ 0,  1,  8],
       [ 2,  2, 24]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Mine on the other hand, is pure numpy. Mainly posted to convince OP to go with pandas :)

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure OP is not looking for `0: 'first'`. The first column is `0, 1`, not `0, 2` in OP's expected result.

Answer (score 4):

A very neat, pure numpy solution is possible using [np.histogram](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

```
A = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],
              [ 1,  1,  6],
              [ 2,  2, 10],
              [ 3,  2, 14]])

c1 = np.unique(A[:, 1])
c0 = np.arange(c1.shape[0])
c2 = np.histogram(A[:, 1], weights=A[:, 2], bins=c1.shape[0])[0]

result = np.c_[c0, c1, c2]

>>> result
array([[ 0,  1,  8],
       [ 1,  2, 24]])
```

When a `weights` array is provided (of the same shape as the input array) to `np.histogram`, any arbitrary element `a[i]` in the input array `a` will contribute `weights[i]` in the count for its bin.

So for example, we are counting the second column, and instead of counting 2 instances of 2, we get 10 instances of 2 + 14 instances of 2 = a count of 28 in 2's bin.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using only numpy arrays...

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2], [ 1,  1,  6], [ 2,  2, 10], [ 3,  2, 14]])

lst = []
compt = 0
for index in range(1, max(arr[:, 1]) + 1):
    lst.append([compt, index, np.sum(arr[arr[:, 1] == index][:, 2])])
lst = np.array(lst)
print lst
# lst, outputs...
# [[ 0  1  8]
# [ 0  2 24]]
```

The tricky part is the `np.sum(arr[arr[:, 1] == index][:, 2])`, so let's break it down to multiple parts.

- `arr[arr[:, 1] == index]` means...

You have an array `arr`, on which we ask numpy the rows that matches the value of the `for` loop. Here, it is set from `1`, to the maximum value of element of the 2nd column (meaning, column with index 1). Printing **only** this expression in the for loop results in...

```
# First iteration
[[0 1 2]
 [1 1 6]]
# Second iteration
[[ 2  2 10]
 [ 3  2 14]]
```

- Adding `[:, 2]` to our expression, it means that we want the value of the 3rd column (meaning index 2), of our above lists. If I print `arr[arr[:, 1] == index][:, 2]`, it would give me... `[2, 6]` at first iteration, and `[10, 14]` at the second.
- I just need to sum these values using `np.sum()`, and to format my output list accordingly. :)

Comment: You are looking for ufunc.reduceat. This can be done without loops. See my answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well, this is why I am on this site : learning from others. I'm taking a look at it, thanks. :)

Comment: I remember the first time someone showed me reduceat. It's arcane but remarkably handy. In general, if you are using loops with numpy arrays, you *probably* need to reconsider your approach.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I already heard this, and I fully agree on it. Except, sometimes in cases like this, I don't have all day to look for a special function that would make my work easier. :'( -- This being said, I was looking for `np.where()` at first, but couldn't figure how to use it. Now I also know that I should have used it in association with `np.diff()`. :p

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary to store the values and then converting back to a list

```
x = [[ 0,  1,  2],
     [ 1,  1,  6],
     [ 2,  2, 10],
     [ 3,  2, 14]]

y = {}
for val in x:
    if val[1] in y:
        y[val[1]][2] += val[2]
    else:
        y.update({val[1]: val})
print([y[val] for val in y])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get exact output use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],
              [ 1,  1,  6],
              [ 2,  2, 10],
              [ 3,  2, 14]])

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.groupby(1).sum().reset_index().reset_index().as_matrix()
#[[ 0 1  8]
# [ 1 2 24]]
```

Comment: `reset_index().reset_index()`?

Comment: Also, you may want to do `reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist First one resets the `groupby` and second one adds new column that contains index values and matches the desired output.

Comment: The result is not what you claim it is... Take a look at your second column vs jpp's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a defaultdict and sum the values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = [[ 0,  1,  2],
    [ 1,  1,  6],
    [ 2,  2, 10]]

res = defaultdict(int)
for val in x:
    res[val[1]]+= val[2]
print ([[i, val,res[val]] for i, val in enumerate(res)])
```

Comment: I think this is not guaranteed to keep the order of the original array (because dictionaries are not sorted)

Comment: I was thinking the same, and I was actually surprised that with integer positive keys in python 3 I always got a sorted result.

Comment: As of a recent Python release, dictionaries are now ordered.

Comment: `list(res.items())` can replace the last statement.