# numpy group by one array and sum another

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to take an array of numpy.bytes_ and compute a grouped sum with another array of weights. So given

```
x = np.array(['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Z'], dtype=np.bytes_)
w = np.array([0, 2, 1, 1])
```

I would like to get something like

```
{'X': 1, 'Y': 2, 'Z': 1}
```

or if numpy has named arrays that would work. The `np.bytes_` array is guaranteed to be single bytes representing ASCII characters and the weights array can be integers or floats.

I've tried using some solutions
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238332/numpy-array-group-by-one-column-sum-another) but I keep getting an exception

```
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'minimum' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('S1'), dtype('S1')) -> None
```

I am not familiar with numpy so I don't know what that exception means or if I should even be trying to do this with numpy. It seems like it would be pretty simple in pandas, but I thought numpy would be more efficient and I didn't want to use pandas just for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.unique(return_inverse=True)` and `np.bincount(weight=...)` to do this, however I don't know if this is faster than pandas.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Z', 'Z', 'Y'], dtype=np.bytes_)
w = np.array([0, 2, 1, 1, 10, 100])

names, groups = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
counts = np.bincount(groups, weights=w)
result = dict(zip(names, counts))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a dictionary comprehension

You can use `if` to exclude items with a `w` value of 0.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Z'], dtype=np.bytes_)
w = np.array([0, 2, 1, 1])

out = {k:v for k,v in zip(x,w) if v>0}
print(out)
```